# Conflicting Constraints (that do not exist) (Swift 4)

Tags: ios, swift

I am rearranging three views like this when the phone is rotated:

[image] [image]

I set constraints as follows:

```
    var narrowConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []
    var wideConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []

    func setConstraints1() {
        
        let cv1Height: CGFloat = 325
        let cv3Height: CGFloat = 125
        
        cv1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cv2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cv3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        // wh
        narrowConstraints = [
            
            // set cv1 height
            cv1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: cv1Height),
            // lock top, left and right to safe area
            cv1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            cv1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            cv1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),

            // lock left and right to safe area
            cv2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            cv2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            
            // lock top of cv2 to bottom of cv1
            cv2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv1.bottomAnchor),
            // lock bottom of cv2 to top of cv3
            cv2.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv3.topAnchor),
            
            // set cv3 height
            cv3.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: cv3Height),
            // lock left, right and bottom to safe area
            cv3.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            cv3.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            cv3.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
        ]
        
        wideConstraints = [

            // lock top, bottom, and left to safe area
            cv1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            cv1.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
            cv1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            // lock right side of cv1 to left side of cv2
            cv1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv2.leadingAnchor),
            
            // lock right side of cv2 to safe area
            cv2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            // lock top of cv2 to safe area
            cv2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            // lock bottom of cv2 to top of cv3
            cv2.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv3.topAnchor),

            // set cv3 height
            cv3.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: cv3Height),
            // lock bottom and right side of cv3 to safe area
            cv3.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            cv3.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
            
            // make them all equal widths
            cv2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv1.widthAnchor),
            cv3.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv2.widthAnchor),            
        ]
        
        if view.frame.width > view.frame.height {
            // if landscape
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(narrowConstraints)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(wideConstraints)
        }
        else { // portrait
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(wideConstraints)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(narrowConstraints)
        }
    }

    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { _ in
            if size.width > size.height {
                // we're transitioning to wider than tall
                NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(self.narrowConstraints)
                NSLayoutConstraint.activate(self.wideConstraints)
            } else {
                // we're transitioning to taller than wide
                NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(self.wideConstraints)
                NSLayoutConstraint.activate(self.narrowConstraints)
            }
        }, completion: {
            _ in
            // if you want to do something after the transition
            //self.cv2.setNeedsDisplay()
        })
    }
```

It all appears to work perfectly - except for the following error message:

```
2020-10-16 14:33:57.364778-0600 ViewPositions2[38358:6108060] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000033a9130 UIView:0x7fb41950ad90.height == 325   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000033aa800 UIView:0x7fb41950ad90.top == UILayoutGuide:0x6000029bcb60'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.top   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000033aa3f0 V:[UIView:0x7fb41950ad90]-(0)-[UIView:0x7fb41950dec0]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000033a9ea0 UIView:0x7fb41950dec0.bottom == UIView:0x7fb41950e8f0.top   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000033a9c70 UIView:0x7fb41950e8f0.height == 125   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000033aa2b0 UIView:0x7fb41950e8f0.bottom == UILayoutGuide:0x6000029bcb60'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.bottom   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000339ff20 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UIView:0x7fb41950f1c0.height == 375   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000339b840 'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide-bottom' V:[UILayoutGuide:0x6000029bcb60'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fb41950f1c0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000339b7a0 'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide-top' V:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x6000029bcb60'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide']   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fb41950f1c0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000033a9130 UIView:0x7fb41950ad90.height == 325   (active)>
```

Through trial and error, I figured out that this error message occurs if the sum of `cv1Height` and `cv2Height` exceeds 375 (the view height in landscape).

But, not only am I deactivating `narrowConstraints` when in landscape, `cv1` is never on top of `cv3` in landscape!

Why is this conflict occurring?  How do I prevent it???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conflict is caused by the appearance of the status bar during the transition.  While you can ignore the warning (it doesn't affect the operation or appearance of your app), it can be silenced by lowering the priority of your `cv1` height constraint in the portrait configuration:

```
let h1 = cv1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: cv1Height)
h1.priority = .defaultHigh
            
narrowConstraints = [
                // set cv1 height
    h1,
                // lock top, left and right to safe area
    cv1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
    cv1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
    cv1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),

                // lock left and right to safe area
    cv2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
    cv2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
                
                // lock top of cv2 to bottom of cv1
    cv2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv1.bottomAnchor),
                // lock bottom of cv2 to top of cv3
    cv2.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv3.topAnchor),
                
                // set cv3 height
    cv3.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: cv3Height),
                // lock left, right and bottom to safe area
    cv3.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
    cv3.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
    cv3.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
]
```

Comment: Fascinating, Captain. Should we regard this as a bug?

Comment: Maybe it's just one of AutoLayout's charming idiosyncrasies?

Comment: Well I would suggest the OP should report it. It’s like those spurious conflict reports on alerts and toolbars, it’s maddening

Comment: Yes.  It isn't hard to create an [mcve], so worth reporting

Comment: @Paulw11 - I just posted another question that seems related:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64539800/view-height-changes-unexpectedly-swift

Is this a bug as well?