# View height changes unexpectedly (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I have set up constraints to allow UIView `cv1` to change height dynamically according to screen size, with the heights of `cv2` and `cv3` fixed.

For some reason, when I run this as shown, `cv3`'s view height becomes 172.

Using the original `cv3.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: cv3Height)` in one or the other or both, I run into the same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64296915/conflicting-constraints-that-do-not-exist-swift-4) (which worked perfectly for `cv2`), with the added effect that where I replace it with `h3,` (narrow or wide) the view jumps to 172 only in that orientation but also gives me the conflicting constraints message.

I deleted ALL other constraints without luck.

Is this another bug?  If so, is there a workaround?

Here is a minimized function, the entire function below:

```
func setConstraints() {
            
    cv3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
    
    let cv3Height: CGFloat = 125
    let h3 = cv3.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: cv3Height)
    h3.priority = .defaultHigh
    
    narrowConstraints = [
        // set cv3 height
        //cv3.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: cv3Height),
        h3, 

        // lock left, right and bottom to safe area
        cv3.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
        cv3(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
        cv3(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
    ]
    
    wideConstraints = [
        // set cv3 height
        //cv3.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: cv3Height),
        h3, 

        // lock bottom and right side of cv3 to safe area
        cv3(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
        cv3(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
        
        // make them all equal widths
        cv2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv1.widthAnchor),
        cv3.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv2.widthAnchor),
    ]

    
    // activate the commonConstraints
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(commonConstraints)
    
    if view.frame.width > view.frame.height {
        // wider than tall, so "landscape"
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(narrowConstraints)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(wideConstraints)
    } else {
        // taller than wide
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(wideConstraints)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(narrowConstraints)
    }
    
}
```

Here is the entire function:

```
func setConstraints() {
    
    cv1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cv2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cv3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
    
    let cv2Height: CGFloat = 190
    let h2 = cv2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: cv2Height)
    h2.priority = .defaultHigh
    
    let cv3Height: CGFloat = 125
    let h3 = cv3.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: cv3Height)
    h3.priority = .defaultHigh
    
    narrowConstraints = [
        
        // lock top, left and right to safe area
        cv1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
        cv1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
        cv1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
        
        // set cv2 height
        //cv2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: cv2Height),
        h2,

        // lock left and right to safe area
        cv2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
        cv2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
        
        // lock top of cv2 to bottom of cv1
        cv2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv1.bottomAnchor),
        // lock bottom of cv2 to top of cv3
        cv2.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv3.topAnchor),
        
        // set cv3 height
        //cv3.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: cv3Height),
        h3, 

        // lock left, right and bottom to safe area
        cv3.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
        cv3(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
        cv3(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
    ]
    
    wideConstraints = [
        
        // lock top, bottom, and left to safe area
        cv1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
        cv1.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
        cv1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
        // lock right side of cv1 to left side of cv2
        cv1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv2.leadingAnchor),
        
        // lock right side of cv2 to safe area
        cv2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
        // lock top of cv2 to safe area
        cv2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
        // lock bottom of cv2 to top of cv3
        cv2.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv3.topAnchor),
        
        // set cv3 height
        //cv3.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: cv3Height),
        h3, 

        // lock bottom and right side of cv3 to safe area
        cv3(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
        cv3(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
        
        // make them all equal widths
        cv2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv1.widthAnchor),
        cv3.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv2.widthAnchor),
    ]

    
    // activate the commonConstraints
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(commonConstraints)
    
    if view.frame.width > view.frame.height {
        // wider than tall, so "landscape"
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(narrowConstraints)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(wideConstraints)
    } else {
        // taller than wide
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(wideConstraints)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(narrowConstraints)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Did you examine the View Debugger to see if it has any help to give?

Comment: I've looked through it but don't see anything.   (I am probably too new to understand what I am looking for.)

Comment: I did just discover that if I set the height in IB and delete the constraint from the func, it works!  Not the solution I am looking for, but if gets me to the next phase for the time being, I'll take it!

Comment: I've also found that ````cv3```` will always be between 172 and 208.  If I set its height to 30 it will end up at 172; if I set it to 500 it will end up at 208.  However, anything in between "appears" to work properly - setting it to 187 ends up at 187.

Comment: What is `cv3`? It is acting a lot like a UIPickerView.

Comment: ````cv1````, ````cv2````, and ````cv3```` are each a UIView.  (short for "custom view")

Comment: (Tip: to achieve `inline code formatting`, only single backticks are necessary. Singles are much easier to add and to edit. Triples are only necessary for block formatting, and quadruples are never necessary - even if they will still work).

Comment: This is a `test`.

Comment: @ halfer:  Cool!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I looks like the issue is the every time the function is called, you're creating new constraints but not deactivating the old constraints from the previous time it was run.

For example, the first time it's called it'll create a set of wide and narrow constraints and activate the wide set. The next time it's called it'll create a new set of wide and narrow constraints and activate the narrow constraints from the second set without deactivating the wide constraints from the first set. Your call to deactivate it being called on the second set which would have on effect.

I'd guess the conflicting constraints message is showing the constraints from the first set that haven't been deactivated.

---

What I would do is split your function into two separate functions.

Make a `setupConstraints` function that only creates the arrays of constraints and activates just the `commonConstraints`. The important part would be to make sure this function is called only once.

Make a `activateConstraintsForOrientation` function that only contains the if statement at the bottom of your function. You'd then call this function anytime you think the orientation has changed.

Comment: The only time I call the function is in ````override func viewDidLoad()````.

Comment: But just to be sure, I tried two things:  I moved it to ````override func viewWillAppear```` and I added  
````NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(narrowConstraints) NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(wideConstraints)```` at the top of the function, but neither solved the problem.

Comment: Could you post the unsatifyable constraints warning you're getting? That would be a lot of useful info.

Comment: I'm not getting any warning since I changed the priority to deal with ````cv2```` and ````cv3```` height anchors.  The warnings appear to be a bug (which I have reported), caused by the appearance of the status bar during the transition.

Comment: But you can see the warnings I was getting here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64296915/conflicting-constraints-that-do-not-exist-swift-4

Comment: Now the question is what is overriding my height constraint?  And why is it doing it only to ````cv3````?  The intent was for  ````cv1```` to vary in height by fixing ````cv2```` and ````cv3````.